# Сдвинуть div на 10px в верх и в лево

Tags: html, css

Есть div (красный квадрат) с position:absolute, который автоматическти установился в верхнем левом углу:

[image]

Надо его сдвинуть на 10 px в верх и в лево:

[image]

**Вопрос:** как?

p.s. пробовал margin-top:-10px; margin-left:-10px;, получилось так:
[image]

Comment: @michael @Kison размеры сохранились, однако не показывает его за пределами родителя, несмотря на z-index:100, выше которого нет

Comment: Уберите свойство overflow:hidden у родителя или установите overflow:visible, скорее всего проблема изначально в этом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А в чем находиться квадрат?

Попробуйте так

```
.square {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: -10px;
}
```

Comment: Для того чтобы элемент был виден из-за границ родителя необходимо родителю прописать в стилях overflow: visible;

Но опять же для того чтобы сказать наверняка нужно увидеть стили родителя.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте:

```
div.moved-div{
    position:absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: -10px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Для родительского блока при этом необходимо установить: **position: relative;**

Answer (score 0):

`z-index`
 Каждый элемент может находиться как ниже, так и выше других объектов веб-страницы, их размещением по `z`-оси и управляет `z-index`. Это свойство работает только для элементов, у которых значение `position` задано как `absolute`, `fixed` или `relative`.
[Подробнее](http://htmlbook.ru/css/z-index)

Comment: Про z-index уже есть соседний ответ